# Using AOP or Annotations to extend a service functionality

Tags: annotations, aop, aspectj

I would like to know what is the best way in which I can extend an existing functionality (probably by using AOP or Annotations). The scenario which I am looking for is.

We have one service say DisableEmployee which uses an entity Employee which does some validation and then disables access to employee. 
For certain customers I would like to extend this functionality where DisableEmployee not only disables the access but also imposes some penalty points.

One approach would be I extend the base class and then add the additional functionality.

Is it possible (or advisable) to use AOP and annotations here; where in I annotate my  DisableEmployee and then at compile time I weave the additional code into the class. (using aspect) I have read about APT and Velocity which should be able to help me in achieving it.
The reason I am looking at APT because we might have to extend the entity classes also to add some new attributes.

The idea of having this approach is to see if we can classify service extension as a form of cross-cutting functionality (like traditional logging, auditing ....)

Thanks in advance

Comment: I got only now that "aspectj" tag added by Constantiner. Logically this addition isn't correct because AspectJ is only AOP implementation among many others. But practically I agree with his choice (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too general to get reliable answer. But at the moment I cannot see anything what cannot be implemented in AspectJ.